# How do I find() all records unique in certain fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, unique, distinct

I have a list of 'request' objects, each of which has fairly normal activerecord qualities.  The requests table is related to the games table with a join table, 'games_requests,' so that a request has a request.games array.

The question is, is there a way to do a find for the last n unique requests, where uniqueness is defined by the games column and a couple others, but specifically ignores other colums (like the name of the requesting user?)

I saw a syntax like 'find (:all, :limit=>5, :include=>[:games,:stage])' but that was returning duplicates.

Thanks...

EDIT: Thanks to chaos for a great response.  You got me really close, but I still need the returns to be valid request objects: the first 5 records that are distinct in the requested rows.  I could just use the find as you constructed it and then do a second find for the first row in the table that matches each of the sets returned by the first find.

EDIT:

```
Games.find(
    :all, :limit => 5,
    :include => [:games, :requests],
    :group => 'games, whatever, whatever_else'
)
```

...gives an SQL error:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'games' in 'group statement': SELECT * FROM `games`  GROUP BY games
```

I made a few changes for what I assumed to be correct for my project; getting a list of requests instead of games, etc:

```
Request.find(
    :all, :order=>"id DESC", :limit=>5,
    :include=>[:games],   #including requests here generates an sql error
    :group=>'games, etc'  #mysql error:  games isn't an attribute of requests
    :conditions=>'etc'
)
```

I'm thinking I'm going to have to use the :join=> option here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Games.find(
    :all, :limit => 5,
    :include => [:games, :requests],
    :group => 'games, whatever, whatever_else'
)
```

Comment: This returns the games, whatever, and whatever_else columns.  Is there a way to return complete request objects, ejecting only those that fail the uniqueness in these columns?

Comment: Hrm.  Has an issue with 'games' being a virtual attribute through a join table.  (see edited question)

Comment: It's really hard to write something that will work without knowing your actual table structure.  Possibly :group => 'games' should be :group => 'game_id' because that's the name of the column in requests?

Comment: Oh, right, you have a many-to-many.  Yeah, you'll need a :join spec to bring in your games_requests table, then group on the game_id column from that.

Answer (score 6):

Try Rails uniq_by.It also works with association and returns array.

`@document = Model.uniq_by(&:field)`

More [Detail](http://www.brownwebdesign.com/blog/2012/12/rails-uniq_by-unique-results-from-activerecord-relations/)

Comment: Think `uniq_by` is depreciated and replaced by `uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to do this using find_by_sql and GROUP BY:

```
Games.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM games GROUP BY user_id")
```